# Cloud watch log access to an IAM user for only only one specific log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I initially tried with all the json policies in the below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-identity-based-access-control-cwl.html#customer-managed-policies-cwl

And i finally got a solution of giving "list, read, write" access to one specific loggroup for an IAM user by using below JSON policy. But it is able to see the list of other log groups as well. As per the below JSON policy i tired limiting the resource for listing as well. It didn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:GetLogRecord",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:Describe*",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "logs:GetLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/lambda/XXXX:log-stream:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But then i found the tagging as a solution and tried tagging the loggroup and user with same tag and tried below JSON policy. That didn't work either.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "logs:ResourceTag/Team": "Green"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please can someone kindly suggest a way where i could give access to one specific IAM user for only one group to either,  list&read or list,read&write. But that user should not be able to see the other log groups.

Comment: `DescribeLogGroups` is not a resource level action, you can not archive it.

Answer (score 0):

> But it is able to see the list of other log groups as well

That's not something you can do typically within AWS. Generally IAM permissions can't affect on the result of an API action. It can't filter it to only show something in particular. This is one the reasons AWS recommends to isolate workloads by using different accounts, as API calls are only scoped to one account.

In this case, you can either not give access at all or give access to list everything.

Answer (score 0):

**To restrict an IAM user’s access to a single log group** you need to specify the ***ARN*** of that log group in the Resource element of your IAM policy.

> Using an asterisk (*) for the Resource grants access to all resources

which is not suitable for your use case.
Here’s an example of a policy that grants access only to the specified log group.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
      "Action": [
    "logs:GetLogRecord",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
    "logs:Describe*",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents",
        "logs:GetLogEvents"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:SampleLogGroupName:*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have been struggling with the same thing for a while now. The solution we reached consisted in giving `logs:DescribeLogGroups` to all log groups while giving more granular access to queries and livetail.

This way the user sees all the log groups in the main page but can only see streams and perform search and livetail for 1 log group.

The IAM policy goes as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:Describe*",
                "logs:Get*",
                "logs:List*",
                "logs:StartQuery",
                "logs:StopQuery",
                "logs:TestMetricFilter",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents",
                "logs:StartLiveTail",
                "logs:StopLiveTail",
                "cloudwatch:GenerateQuery"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:log-group:SampleLogGroupName:*"
        }
    ]
}
```